# Why PublicKeyToken changed?

Tags: mono.cecil, assembly-binding-redirect, publickeytoken

Attempting to make bindingRedirect from `Mono.Cecil` v`0.9.5` to `0.10.0`, I've found, since v`0.10.0` a `PublicKeyToken` changed.

v`0.9.5`, `0.9.6` (& probably some other <`0.10.0`) have `PublicKeyToken` - *0738eb9f132ed756*

since v`0.10.0` and so on (incl. `0.11.3.0` for example) `PublicKeyToken` - *50cebf1cceb9d05e*

It breaks bindingRedirect with cause "*PublicKeyToken mismatch*".

I wonder, why was it changed (in this case or at general - why do developers change `PublicKeyToken` of their product)?
Is it intend to underline versions incompatibility?

Comment: Where did you get the assembly? The original ones from Mono project should remain the same.

Comment: @LexLi, all of them are got as NuGet-packages from nuget.org

Comment: "The beta 4 was just a repackage of the beta 3 without using the Mono strong name key" on https://cecil.pe/ does indicate an intentional change. But to learn the exact reason you can only ask the author himself.